# Could not find json-1.8.6 in any of the sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rubygems, bundle

When trying to run rails s, I got the above error Could not find json-1.8.6 in any of the sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. This is what I've tried so far:

```
bundle install
bundle update
bundle exec bundle install
bundle update json
gem install json
gem install json -v '1.8.6'
```

Comment: Can you please post your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: I was unable to add my gemfile and gemfile.lock, I kept getting error messages, but in the meantime, I was able to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These commands fixed the issue:

```
brew update
brew install coreutils
```

Then I ran `bundle install` and json loaded properly.